# Craft 3: multisite and assets

Tags: assets, craft3, multi-site

I am a little bit confused by the documentation about assets. It says that paths are relatives from the directory that holds the index.php file.

Now, I am working on multisite, with the following folders:
    craft/web/site1/
    craft/web/site2/

Is it possible to have:
    craft/assets/site1/
    craft/assets/site2/

Or:
    craft/web/site1/assets/
    craft/web/site2/assets/

Comment: If you want your assets to be publicly available I think they would need to be under the `/web` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is easy enough... just make sure the `assets` folder exists under both of the `site1` and `site2` folders, the under your Asset Volume settings in the Control Panel, set the "File System Path" to the relative `assets`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, but that's not easy for me. :-( I created the assets folders, so that I have "craft/web/site1/assets" and "craft/web/site2/assets", but what path do I use? I tried many and when I try to rebuild the cache, Craft says 'Impossible to create the root directory "/assets"'. I know Craft have writing privileges into the sites folders, so what I am missing here?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't being condescending. Just meant that the first example is more complicated. :)

Comment: The path should be just `assets`.  When you set that, are you able to upload a file from the Control Panel?

Comment: Oh, I didn't think you were condescending, just too much familiar with Craft. ;-) I have some progress: I was mislead by Craft recommending me an absolute path (“/path/to/folder”) and I used "/assets" instead of just "assets". Index rebuilding is now working and I can upload files BUT they all go into the "site1/assets" folder.

Comment: In your 2nd site's `index.php` file, did you define the `CRAFT_SITE` PHP constant?  i.e. `define('CRAFT_SITE', 'site2');` where `site2` is whatever th handle for your 2nd site is under Settings->Sites in the Control Panel.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that from the start.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it right, going the first solution I planned. So, in my Craft project directory ("craft"), I created "craft/assets/site1" and "craft/assets/site2" and when going into the admin panel and setting up the ressources, using "../../assets/site1" and "../../assets/site2" did the trick, everything working as expected. So, really, my source of confusion here was Craft recommending me “/path/to/folder” which lead me to add a / at the beginning of my paths; once I got rid of that, problem was solved. Thank you very much for your help ! :-)

Comment: Glad you're all sorted!

Comment: Because you so kindly helped me. Thank you again for that! :-)